# What is the equivalent of "cuckold" for women?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Well, the question is in the title.

I want to know what do you call a woman who has an unfaithful husband but chooses to ignore it.

I searched a word for it but could not succeed. I just do not understand that are there only unfaithful women? What about men?

Comment: http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=291734

Comment: Well, it seems the word is "cuckquean". But, it is obsolete now, so is there such a word in current usage? Thanks for your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

The original word cuckold was derived from "cuckoo", the bird that lays its eggs in other birds' nests so that they raise the hatchlings as their own.  A cuckold (man) could end up in the position of unwittingly raising another man's children as his own.  Since that would never unknowingly happen to a woman, there is no female equivalent of the word cuckold.

Comment: No, I do not mean in the literal sense only a word that implies a similar meaning. But you helped. Thank You.